# create table of time_slot from database system concept by korth

Tags: mysql, database, time, create-table

We all familiar with University dataset that has been given on `Database System Concept` by `Korth`. I would like to create the table

time slot (**time slot id, day, start time,** end time) Bold words are primary key.

I wrote create table command

```
create table time_slot(
                       time_slot_id varchar (4),
                       s_day varchar(2),
                       start_time time,
                       end_time time,
                       primary key(time_slot_id,s_day,start_time));
```

The toy dataset that I have to use is like that

```
insert into time_slot values ('A', 'M', '8', '0', '8', '50');
insert into time_slot values ('A', 'W', '8', '0', '8', '50');
insert into time_slot values ('A', 'F', '8', '0', '8', '50');
insert into time_slot values ('B', 'M', '9', '0', '9', '50');
```

But my table creation type does not match with the dataset. So I could not insert a row.

Any one have any idea what datatype I need to change to create the table.

Comment: everybody may be familiar with this dataset, but I've never heard of it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your insert has integer hours and minutes for start and end time while the table has `time` type fields that should be provided like `08:00:00`, `09:50:00`.  Either change your create table to match the inserts or (recommended) change your inserts to match the table.

Comment: I cannot change the insert command. So what modification is needed in the create table command?

Comment: have separate int-type start_time_hour, start_time_minute, end_time_hour, end_time_minute columns instead of start_time and end_time

Comment: There is a quote in the time. So isn't it varchar?

Comment: also remove start_time from the primary key. maybe you want start_time_hour and start_time_minute there?  not clear to me why the primary key is what it is

Comment: mysql will convert it to a number as needed.  if you actually have non-numeric data or need to preserve leading zeroes or something, make it a varchar, looking at your data to see what the width should be

Comment: did you get the create table from https://github.com/wflyer/silberschatz-6th-university-dataset ?  that also has inserts with actual times; maybe you are working with a different edition.  in which case there are likely to be other differences too.  you really should look at your data to come up with your own create table statements.

Comment: I can not remove start_time from primary key because it is database requirement.

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69905335/find-the-number-of-students-who-has-not-taken-any-course-offered-before-2018       This is another question I am struggling on.

Comment: but your data does not have a single start_time field, it has it split into two.  so you are misinterpreting the requirement